# How to use struct formatting for PHP SOAP request

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I am trying to make a SOAP request using PHP.

With the following parameters I am getting this error:

```
$soapURL = 'http://my.simpleviewcrm.com/webapi/listings/soap/listings.cfc?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($soapURL, array('trace' => true));

    $listingRequest = array(
            'username'  => 'someuser',
            'password'  => 'somepass',
            'pagenum'   => 15,
            'pagesize'  => 10,
        'filters'   => array(
                    'FieldCategory' => 'Listing',
                    'FieldName'     => 'Listingid',
                    'FilterType'    => 'Equal To',
                    'FilterValue'   => 13,
                ),
            'displayamentities' => 1
    );

    $listingResponse = $client->__soapCall("getListings", $listingRequest);

    //echo 'Request: ' . $client->__getLastRequest() .'';

    echo "</br><h3>Listing Response</h3>";
    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($listingResponse);
    print '</pre>';
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
array(2) {
  ["DATA"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["STATUS"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["RESULTS"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ERRORS"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["MESSAGE"]=>
        string(44) "Element FILTERS is undefined in FILTERGROUP."
        ["DETAIL"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["TYPE"]=>
        string(10) "Expression"
      }
    }
    ["HASERRORS"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Any help as to why its not taking my filters?

Documentation here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbryi7syan7wt9a/Listings%20API%20Documentation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not forming your request message for getListings as per required by your operation.

As per your document (page 24), Filters is defined under FilterGroup. and each filter fields should be under items tag.So please form your request message like this in above code

```
<getListings>
        <username>data</username>
        <password>data</password>
        <pagenum>data</pagenum>
        <pagesize>data</pagesize>
<FILTERGROUP>
        <FILTERS>
            <ITEM>
               <FILTERTYPE>data</FILTERTYPE>
               <FIELDCATEGORY>data</FIELDCATEGORY>
               <FILTERVALUE>data</FILTERVALUE>
                <FIELDNAME>data</FIELDNAME>
             </ITEM>
        </FILTERS>
 <FILTERGROUP>
 </getListings>
```